# ConcurrentModificationException in removing element in ArrayList [Using iterator.remove()]

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, concurrentmodification

i know that we shouldn't modify the ArrayList during iteration.

But i'm using Iterator to iterate over list and iterator.remove() to remove the element but still results in ConcurrentModification Exception.

My program is not multithreaded.

I've many arraylist [class contains it and i'm processing many array of objects]

```
for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    if(k==i) continue;

    it = obj[i].arraylist.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
    value = it.next();

      if(condn)  {
       it.remove();
       obj[k].arraylist.add(value);
       //k and i are not same 

      }

    }
```

}

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

> "Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection
>   during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying
>   collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in
>   progress."

You can remove objects but not add new ones during the iteration, that's why you get that ConcurrentModificationException.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Edit: 
You can also check:

```
if(k==i || obj[i].arraylist == obj[k].arraylist) continue;
```

Comment: Even if he is adding to another list? Mind "i" and "k" are made sure to be not the same. So I assume obj[i].arraylist and obj[k].arraylist are not the same instances, too.

Comment: @Fildor You are sure 'i' and 'k' are different, indeed, but you can't assume that the arraylists within obj[i] and obj[k] are not the same objects.

Comment: If that is the case, then we have the flaw detected :) BTW: it should continue if the instances _are_ the same, so, it should be `obj[i].arraylist == obj[k].arraylist)` , right?

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify the List during iteration using `it` variable.